# Find in which week the given datetime fall in a range of datetime

Tags: c#

Let's suppose if I have a datetime range from:
`2020-07-01 08:00` to `2020-07-21 10:25`

I need to check if in which week number does the input date fall. The day of the week is the day in which `d1` is.

```
DateTime d1 =
DateTime.ParseExact("2020-07-01 08:00", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime d2 =
DateTime.ParseExact("2020-07-21 10:25", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

List<int> weeks = new List<int>();
var Week = (int)Math.Floor((double)d1.DayOfYear / 7.0); //starting week number
for (DateTime t = d1; t < d2; t = t.AddDays(7))
{
    weeks.Add(Week);
    Week++;
}
```

Here **three** dates will be used, d1 and d2 are the range of date, they are constant by default, we cannot vary them.

But we need to find the week number of only the third date which will be only input.

Example: If I pass the input as:

```
Example 1: If input as `2020-07-03 08:00` the output should be returned as: Week 1
Example 2: If input as `2020-07-08 09:35` the output should be returned as: Week 2
```

Comment: [`Calendar.GetWeekOfYear`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.calendar.getweekofyear?view=netcore-3.1)?

Comment: not the calendar week, but the week number in the range..like week 1, week 2 or 3.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow the question. Some exact sample inputs and outputs would be helpful, I think

Answer (score 0):

You can use find days difference and use simple logic to print. See below code which print all weeks as you have asked in your question:

```
DateTime d1 = DateTime.ParseExact("2020-06-28 19:41:00", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        DateTime d2 = DateTime.ParseExact("2020-08-03 22:00:00", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        
        int diffDay = (d2 - d1).Days;
        int currentWeek = 0;
        while (currentWeek < diffDay)
        {
            var week = (currentWeek / 7) + 1;
            Console.WriteLine("Week" + week);
            currentWeek = currentWeek + 7;
        }
```

To print only the week in which date will fall

```
var week = $"week {((d2 - d1).Days / 7) + 1}";
```

Comment: d1 and d2 are the constant date range, that is not the input.. we have to check in which week third date fall. between the range of d1 and d2.

Comment: @AakashBashyal - d2 is not relevant. suppose third date is d3 so calculate the week use `$"week {((d3 - d1).Days / 7) + 1}";` which will return the week from d1.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in one comment you can use

```
Calendar.GetWeekOfYear
```

So to solve your problem:

```
Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(d3) - Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(d1)
```

You will need to ensure d3 is withing the date range for validation purposes

Comment: not the weeks in the year..but the week inside the date range of d1 and d2.